# C multiple struct with only one node

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, nodes

After juggling and trying to learn how to get this done I thought it's time to ask the experts.

I have more than one structures and would like to "manipulate" the data in them using only one node.

What is the best way to do this?

code example:

```
typedef struct printQuality{ int dpi; } quality ;
    typedef struct paperSize{ char* dim; } sizes ; //this would be A3 , A4 this is why i picked char
    typedef struct printColour{ char* color; } colors;
    typedef struct printStyle{ char* side; } sides;
    typedef struct printOrientation { char* orientation; } orientations;

typedef union printOptions{
    quality dpi;
    sizes size;
    colors color;
    sides side;
    orientations orientation;

} options;

struct optNode{
    options* inf;
    optNode* next;
    optNode* prev;
};
```

Comment: Please give code example what is working/not-working

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide more details regarding what you're asking. When you do so, please keep in mind that we can't read your mind or see your screen from where we're sitting, so the only information we have available to us is what you put in your question.

Comment: typedef struct? So you are writing C code, why do you use the C++ tag?

Comment: Make an [mcve]. Get it compilable by making comments of anything which causes errors. Write in prose comments what those things are supposed to achieve. Make sure to include some code which demonstrates how you are intending to use your quaint structure types.

Comment: It seems like you want to access both an instance of printOptions and an instance of printQuality from an instance of optNode. Is that correct?

Comment: @JaysonBoubin I am trying to access instances of all the structs above, trough an instance of printOptions from an instance of optNode

Comment: So you want an optNode to contain an instance of printOptions which then contains an instance of all of your structs?

Comment: @JaysonBoubin precisely.
I can deal with one struct, one node, insertion and deletion of data in the struct and that's simple. But when I want to have multiple structs, that's where I need help.
I do not want to write separate nodes, and separate functions for each.

Comment: You're using a union for your print options which contains instances of all of these structs. Are you trying to access them all at the same time? or do you only need one struct value per option node? (I.E, does each node need a dpi, size, etc, or just one of those values)

Comment: @JaysonBoubin trying to access all of them at the same time.
I know what a union is supposed to do. And I was trying to somewhat make the node interpret the structures as one.

Comment: Somewhere along the line, you need a 'discriminator' to tell you which value is stored in a given occurrence of the union — search on 'discriminated union c' with Google shows Dr Dobbs articles and Stack Overflow questions high on the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments, I believe your issue has to do with the behavior of Unions in C vs structs. In C/C++, Unions are structures which can only instantiate one of their values at a given time. With your printOptions union, you have 5 variables. At any given time, only one of those variables (the last one you set) is guaranteed to hold a value. Here is a good article on how Unions work: https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-unions. Structs in C/C++ do not have this behavior. Whichever values you set remain set until the instance of the struct goes out of scope or is deleted. I think that if you make printOptions a struct, you will be able to access all of your other structs from your options pointer in your optNodes.

Comment: Indeed this seemed a viable solution to my issues. And now, I have the opinion of the experts.
Thank you.